# Trailhead Amazon CTI SSO popup doesn't close

Tags: trailhead

I had completed [Build an Amazon Connect Integration](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-an-amazon-connect-integration) and moved on to complete [Build an Amazon Connect SSO Integration with Salesforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-an-amazon-connect-sso-integration-with-salesforce) which is essentially the same thing but with SSO authentication into Amazon Connect instead of username/pw.

On reaching the step of [testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-an-amazon-connect-sso-integration-with-salesforce/finalize-single-signon-and-test-the-softphone?trail_id=innovate-with-alexa-and-amazon-web-services#test-your-telephony-now-with-sso), the SSO process only appears to be partially working.
The expected behaviour is there is a popup that does the SSO which on completion closes, and the CTI phone page within the lightning service console becomes available.
Instead what I am seeing is the popup doesn't close, but redirects to the Amazon connect softphone. This means that I am authenticating on the AWS side, but the softphone within salesforce remains unavailable.

I retraced the trailhead steps, and also read through the latest newly released [amazon docs](https://connect-blogs.s3.amazonaws.com/Amazon+Connect+Salesforce+CTI+Adapter/Amazon+Connect+CTI+Adapter+for+Salesforce+Lightning+-+Setup+and+Installation+Guide.pdf) but can't seem to find anything I have done different to what is described. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up 2 domains the Application Integration on Amazon Connect Console. One is the visualforce domain and one another is salesforce console domain.

```
https://hogehoge--amazonconnect.visualforce.com
https://hogehoge.lightning.force.com
```

Probably, you may enter only one, visualforce domain. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Two possible causes.. first one is as noted above - adding the sf url's. There is another possible cause/solution.

In our case we had used just the prefix of our Connect instance name in the "Amazon Connect Instance" field in the CTI adapter setup in Saleforce. This worked fine for non SSO but when you used SSO, it wants the FULL URL to your Connect Instance. So instead of just "xyz" you need to enter https://xyz.my.connect.aws